# setting xdebug.coverage_enable=On on command line for PHPunit

Tags: phpunit

I don't want to turn on xdebug code coverage for all scripts but I do want to be able to turn it on for a daily jenkins build which produces the code coverage.

I tried the following

```
phpunit -d xdebug.coverage_enable=1 -c phpunit-coverage.xml.dist
```

However I always get the following error

```
Configuration read from phpunit-coverage.xml.dist


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeCoverage_Exception' with message 'You need to set xdebug.coverage_enable=On in your php.ini.' in /usr/local/lib/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Driver/Xdebug.php on line 72

PHP_CodeCoverage_Exception: You need to set xdebug.coverage_enable=On in your php.ini. in /usr/local/lib/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Driver/Xdebug.php on line 72

Call Stack:
    0.0002     627488   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0050    1095880   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:46
    0.0050    1096608   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
    0.6419   39830848   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:192
    0.9760   40345400   5. PHP_CodeCoverage->__construct() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:258
    0.9764   40358504   6. PHP_CodeCoverage_Driver_Xdebug->__construct() /usr/local/lib/php/PHP/CodeCoverage.php:119
```

Any ideas as to how I can get this to work, without having to change php.ini each time?

Comment: When you want code-coverage for the test-run, you need to enable it. If you don't want it, you do not enable it. It looks like you disable it when you want it for the test-run.

Comment: Can you not use the Bootstrap functionality to enable the INI setting?

Comment: I didn't try that as my bootstrap file is generated by Symfony2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I discovered you cannot do what I originially wanted.

Instead the answer is to add second php.ini file which has xdebug and coverage enabled. Then
in my build.xml I used the following to run it.

```
php -c /usr/local/lib/php-coverage.ini /usr/bin/phpunit -c app/
```

Comment: i think you can now. phpStorm's command line includes -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1

Answer (score 18):

Yes it can, but you have to pass the command-line .ini args to php first:

```
php -d xdebug.mode=coverage bin/phpunit --coverage-clover='reports/coverage/coverage.xml' --coverage-html='reports/coverage'
```

Note: "..Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.coverage_enable' has been renamed,.."

Answer (score 10):

With php 7.4 and phpunit 9, it's possible set options with env

```
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage /usr/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 2):

Using php 7.4 I has to use `-d xdebug.mode=coverage`

Because I use `php -n` my full line was `-d zend_extension=xdebug.so -d xdebug.mode=coverage`